# How to align Image beside text inside the container?

Tags: html, css

Here is the JS Fiddle the full code

http://jsfiddle.net/0ad96zyr/1/

```
.ads-container
{
 width: 274px;
 height: 913px;
 margin-top:  55px;
}
```

Here's my container

it should be like this http://imgur.com/nRJpbPA

I tried to use float and align but it doesnt work kindly help me please.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to remove `float: left` from `.ads-prod-text` and play with the `margin` and `padding` a little. No positioning needed:

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/0ad96zyr/4/)

**CSS**

```
.ads-container{
   width: 274px;
   height: 913px;
   margin-top:  55px;
}

.ads-ul{
    list-style-type: none;  
}

.ads-li{
    width: 274px;
    height: 185px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    padding: 8px; //add padding to container for spacing      
}

.ads-prod-title{
   text-align: left;
   display: inline-block; //add so it doesnt take full width
}

.ads-prod-icons{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    float:right;
}

.ads-prod-img{
   float: left;
   margin: 20px 0 0 0; //add for spacing        
}

.ads-prod-text{
  /*float: left;*/ //remove
   margin: 40px 0 0; //add for spacing        
}
```

Comment: @user3626061 you got it

Answer (score 0):

You have to absolute position the text and give a specified width to it like this http://jsfiddle.net/0ad96zyr/2/

```
.ads-prod-text{
left:130px;  
width:120px;
position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a width on your `ads-prod-text` class.

http://jsfiddle.net/Delorian/5mf170fb/

```
.ads-prod-text {
    float: left;
    width: 177px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ads-prod-text
{

     width : 170px;  /* new added, but depend on width on container  */
     float: left;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0ad96zyr/5/  updated :)